# DIV background-color does not fill 100% height when scrolling

Tags: html, css

When I scroll down my div background-color still does not update, 
it's 100% height to the bottom of the page. See my screenshot here:

[image]

See the following code on my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/p7v39xot/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
body {
        width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;
        background: orange; color: #000000;
        font-family: "Century Gothic", "Apple Gothic", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#container {
        width: 800px; height: 100%;
        position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}
#page {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 1.1em;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 3px; right: 3px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="page">
    <u>Page Title</u>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <b>Content</b><br /><br /><br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />Lorem Ipsum<br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I tell the div `#page` to stretch its white background-color 
further on to the bottom of the page when I scroll down?

If I use `min-height: 100%;` and `position: relative;` in `#page` it
produces the scrollbar on the right:

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to use height: 100%? Could you try min-height: 100% instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `position: absolute` to `position: relative`

Add this

```
#page {
  position: relative;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7v39xot/2/)

You can add `min-height:100%`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7v39xot/3/)

Comment: When I add min-height:100% to #page then I get the scrollbar also there is no need to scroll.

Comment: @udgru. you have padding added to #page you should remove or decrease the min-height

Answer (score 2):

simply add this to your css class :

```
height: fit-content;
```

happy coding ^^

Comment: This answer deserves 1000 updvotes

Answer (score 0):

I have added:

```
min-height: 90%
box-sizing: box-sizing;
margin-bottom: 1.1em;
```

to the page and removed the absolute position.

http://jsfiddle.net/p7v39xot/4/